# What is the relation between the dimension of a subspace and the number of independent vectors it does (not) contain?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let's say we have the subspace W of $\mathbb{R}_4$ with the basis {(1,1,1,0),(0,0,0,1)}.

dim(W) = 2, but it seems (and I may be wrong) that it is possible to find more than 2 independent vectors not included in W, eg (1,0,0,0); (0,1,0,0); (0,0,1,1)

Am I missing something or am I completely wrong?

Sorry if the latter.

Comment: yes you're right in saying that $\sigma = \{(1,0,0,0), (0,1,0,0), (0,0,1,1) \}$ is a linearly independent subset of $\mathbb{R}^4$ which does not intersect $W$.

Comment: I'm guessing that your confusion is that you are wondering: since $W$ is two dimensional, but $\text{span}(\sigma)$ is $3$-dimensional, how we can have something "$3+2=5$" dimensional in $\mathbb{R^4}$, which is only $4$-dimensional? Is that your confusion?

Comment: @peek-a-boo yes that's a better way of expressing of what I was asking

Comment: in that case, notice that although $W$ is 2-dimensional, but span$(\sigma)$ is $3$ dimensional, the intersection of these subspaces is $1$-dimensional. Indeed, notice that  the $5$ vectors you have written down are linearly DEPENDENT. $(1,1,1,0) + (0,0,0,1) - (1,0,0,0) - (0,1,0,0) - (0,0,1,1) = (0,0,0,0)$

Comment: I hope you see that there is no contradiction going on anywhere; you just need to keep track of which sets you're intersecting: $W \cap \sigma = \emptyset$ but $W \cap \text{span}(\sigma)$ is $1$-dimensional (this accounts for the seemingly "extra" dimension in $5$ vs $4$)

Comment: Another possible source of misconception you might have is that "the union of linearly independent sets is linearly independent". This however is a false statement

Comment: @peek-a-boo I think I pretty much got it with your second answer. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about a simpler example to visualize your error. Let's say we're in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $W = span\{(1,0)\}$. Note every two distinct vectors $(a,b)$ with $a^2 + b^2 = 1$, $a > 0$, $b \neq 0$ are linearly independent (graphicaly, it's just a representation of the right-side of the unit semi-circunference).

Answer (score 0):

You’re looking at a set of exactly three vectors and comparing it to the infinite set $W$. We can even add another vector to this set: $(0,0,1,0)$. None of these vectors lie in $W$, but that doesn’t mean that their *span* only has the trivial intersection with $W$. With the additional vector, that’s obviously false: The four vectors span all of $\mathbb R^4$. It’s not too hard to work out that the span of your original three vectors intersects $W$ along the one-dimensional space spanned by $(1,1,1,1)^T$.